# why mysql query is failing

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

```
mysql> select name,family from member as d 
 where mov in(select d.mov from d);
```

.

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'film.d' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Looks like it can't identify the "d" in (select d.mov from d)...I'd try something like  select d.name,d.family from member d where d.mov in(select c.mov from anotherTableName c);

Comment: an odd-looking query. The `in()` part appears to be redundant as it's trying to include from a list of every value of the same field from the same table. Eh?

Comment: What you just said was: **select name,family from member where mov in (select mov from member)**  Which would be the same as **select name,family from member**

Comment: Dan i know what you say but i want to use from d

Answer (score 2):

`d` in your subquery `(select d.mov from d)` is not a valid table name. Are you trying to do some kind of correlated query with the member table by using the alias d here?

Comment: @mehdi: You tell me; it's your database. Do you have a table named `d` in this database? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps then we can offer a better alternative query.

Comment: no,but it is a alias table.  select name,family from member **as d**

Comment: @mehdi, You can't reference a table alias that way and, even if you could, that subquery really serves no purpose. You'll get the same results with just `select name,family from member`

Answer (score 0):

mysql is looking for table d which is definitely does not exists.

```
select name,family from member d 
 where mov in(select d.mov from member d);
```

`d` is not valid because you can not use alias of outer query to inner query (sub query). You have to redefine the alias for table in sub query.

Comment: What you just said was: **select name,family from member where mov in (select mov from member)**  Which would be the same as **select name,family from member**

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that the query doesn't actually do anything besides select all rows in the member table, the reason it isn't working is that you cannot use an outside alias 'd' inside your subquery.  Try this:

```
SELECT name, family FROM member WHERE mov in (SELECT mov from member)
```